# JS Promises - If Statement within a Promise

Tags: mongodb

Saying I have a promise in the form of a MongoDB lookup:

```
User.findOne({publicID: id}, function (err, userInfo) {
      if ( userInfo.person.indexOf(id) > -1 ){
        okCheck = true;
      }     
})
.then(function() {
   //Next Steps
}
```

So i understand that it will go into the `//Next Steps` once the `User.findOne` has been completed but I also need for that if statement to be computed as well.

How do i essentially put that If section into that promise as well?

Is this a correct solution?

```
User.findOne({publicID: id}, function (err, userInfo) {
     return userInfo
})
.then(function(userInfo) {
if ( userInfo.person.indexOf(id) > -1 ){
    okCheck = true;
  } 
}
.then(function() {
   //Next Steps
}
```

Comment: @Amit why did you remove those two tag? `javascript` & `promise`

Comment: Its Javascript related is it not - the question is around  promises, MongoDB is just the example

Comment: findOne is using a callback, why don't you just do whatever you want to do in the promise in the callback?

Comment: Because this is about **mongodb**. It's not a typical way to use promises, and a general "promise" answer is not what you need. Typically you either do callback or promise. From the code looks like you mix both. This is mongodb specific.

Comment: You mean use multiple `then` statements? If so, how would the `if` statement have a promise linked to it?

Comment: Why are you trying to create a promise chain instead of using the callbacks? just do the //Next Steps after the if statement inside of the callback function

Comment: @bryan60 ok i see - but say I had multiple things to do step by step. i don't want to go into the Next Steps section unless that if statement has been computed

Comment: Then just call another function from the callback?

Comment: Updated my question - is the code at the bottom what you mean?

Comment: @userMod2 your code of using findOne is incorrect. You either provide a callback as the second parameter or just let `findOne` return a promise.